Alamofire: How to prevent/debounce parallel request to the same ressource
I'm developing an iOS app where I make various JSON/REST calls to the server. Various party of my application need data from various endpoints and it can happen, that different parts of the application want to access data from the same resource. This works fine if the resource was loaded previously and the response is in my local cache.
However, when I start the app for the first time, it can happen, that two processes try to load the same resource. Instead of making 2 parallel requests or building a mechanism where all calls are made sequential, I look for a possibility to let Alamofire handle the duplicate requests so that only one request is made to the server but both processes get the response.
If I were to build this by myself, I probably would need some kind of queue and callback mechanism where the processes write requests to a queue which I would throttle/debounce but the invoking processes would also need to register themselves as a callback once the process behind the queue actually made the network call and wants to return the response.
From an architectural standpoint, this would make my app a lot more complicated so I wanted to ask if there is an out-of-the-box solution in Alamofire which I might not be aware of.

I would suggest create your own share class and inside that class you can store in progress request using that you can make decision to create new request or attach with existing one
